# If booklets are little books, what are pamphlets?

Tags: etymology

If booklets are little books, what are pamphlets?

Little "pamphs"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, the term doesn't appear to be a diminutive of anything. According to this reference [here](http://www.artandpopularculture.com/Pamphlet)...

> The adverb pamphlet for a small work (opuscule) issued by itself without covers came into Middle English ca 1387 as pamphilet or panflet, generalized from a twelfth-century amatory comic poem with a old flavor, Pamphilus, seu de Amore ("Pamphilus: or, Concerning Love"), written in Latin. Pamphilus's name was derived from Greek, meaning "friend of everyone". The poem was popular and widely copied and circulated on its own, forming a slim codex.
>
> Its modern connotations of a tract
>   concerning a contemporary issue was a
>   product of the heated arguments
>   leading to the English Civil War; this
>   sense appeared in 1642.

Answer (score 0):

Flyer?

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyer_(pamphlet)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyer_%28pamphlet%29)

Comment: @Bogdan: "If booklets are little books, what are pamphlets?" the answer(here) is pamphlets are Fyler.

Comment: in that case "flylets"?